# Efficient synchronization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, synchronization, dataset

Lets say I have a large sorted (+10 MB, +650k rows) dataset on **node_a** and different dataset on **node_b**. There is no master version of the dataset, meaning that either node can have some pieces which are not available to other node. My goal is to have a content of **node_a** synchronized with content of **node_b**. What is the most efficient way to do so?

Common sense solution would be:

node_a: Here's everything I have... (sends entire dataset)

node_b: Here's what you don't have... (sends missing parts)

But this solution is not efficient at all. It requires the **node_a** to send (+10 MB) every time he attempts to synchronize.

So this time using a little brainpower I could introduce a partitioning of the dataset, sending only a part of entire content and expect differences found between first and last row of the part.

Can you think of any better solutions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

Comment: Have `node_a` keep track of changes that were made since the last time it synchronized. Have `node_b` do the same thing. Then all they have to send is the deltas.

Answer (score 0):

**For a single synchronization:**

Break the dataset up into arbitrary parts, hash each (with [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5), for example), and only send through the hash values instead of the whole data set. Then use a comparison of the hash values on the other side to determine what's not the same on each side, and send this through as appropriate.

If each part doesn't have a global unique ID (i.e. a primary key that's guaranteed to be the same for the corresponding row on each side), you may need some meta-data sent across as well, or send hashes of parts incrementally, determining the difference as you go, and changing what you send if required (e.g. send the hash of 10 rows at a time, if you find a missing row, there will be a mismatch of the rows - either cater for this on the receiver-side, or offset the sender by one row). How exactly this should be done will depend on what your data looks like.

**For repeated synchronization:**

A good idea might be to create a master version, and store this separately on one of the nodes, although this probably isn't necessary if you don't care about conflicts or being able to revert mistakes.

With or without a master version, you can use versioning here. Store the version of last synchronize, and store a version on each part. When synchronizing, just send the parts with a version higher than the last synchronize version.

As an alternative to a globally auto-incremented version, you could either use a timestamp as the version, or just have a modified flag on each part, setting it when modified, sending all parts with their flag set, and resetting the flags once synchronized.